# How to import the LibGdx sample project

Tags: java, import, libgdx

I need to import the project as mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/Matsemann/libgdx-loading-screen).

I am not using git, hence I have downloaded the project zip folder and extracted. Could you please let me know how to import this LibGdx sample project ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could import project from any IDE you use? Which IDE do you use? Eclipse, InteliJ, AndroidStudio?

Comment: I tried but no projects are getting listed in it

Comment: So did you follow the documentation to setup your development environment? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29 As the documentation states you need to import them as a gradle project, thus you need the gradle plugin. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Running-Demos

Comment: That's Eclipse. I can see that that is Eclipse. Don't use Eclipse. Use Android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is about 3 years ago, perhaps the APIs libgdx not be supported 100% by the cycle of listener aplication, or the project will not be prepared to be exported, and is a simple guide. I do not know the truth but looking at the repo what comes to mind is the following.

I think the easiest wayIt would create a new project, libgdx.

Copy, android asset data folder in to the new project android asset, and the Main folder, extract all files and copy to the core of the new project. change name `package com.matsemann.libgdxloadingscreen;` for you packege name and change other posible error in the files.

Take the class SomeCoolGame in "SomeCoolGame.java":

```
package com.matsemann.libgdxloadingscreen;
//
public class SomeCoolGame extends Game {

    /**
     * Holds all our assets
     */
    public AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    @Override
    public void create() {
        setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this));
    }
}
```

as an entry point and adapt more or less something, eh not test but it's just so you can see the idea

```
package your.name.package;
//
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    /**
     * Holds all our assets
     */
    public AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    @Override
    public void create() {
        setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this));
    }
}
```

and work starting from there.